# Exclude Glacier and Deep Glacier Storage Types from Glue Crawler

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, amazon-glacier

I'm looking for a way to exclude Glacier and Deep glacier storage types when using Glue S3 Crawler, is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I've heard back from AWS, this is not currently supported.

I've requested this to be added as a feature.

The interim work around is to use exclude patterns.